# how to convert a select statement into a update statement

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

How do I have to convert this select statement into a update statement?

(goal: calculate the weight increasement)

```
select we.*,
        we.weight_evening - (select weight_evening
                             from Weight
                             where color = pg.color          
                             and date < we.date             
                             order by we.date desc
                             limit 1                            
                            ) as weight_increasement
from Weight we
where color = "red"
```

Comment: What do you want to `UPDATE`? Which table and which column?

Comment: I want to update the column weight_increasement of table Weight

Comment: nobody can help me?